# Negative values in the dicom image of a CT Scan

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

Generally, CT Scan images are grayscale in nature. I have obtained dicom images from a medical institute but they have negative intensities in them, while a general dicom image is supposed to have values ranging from 0 - 255 in MATLAB. Is there any way where i can work around the values from negative to the normal 0 - 255 range, without truncating other values or distorting the image?

Comment: Can you provide us with example data? What do the negative intensities represent? Can you just set them to zero? Or do you have to rescale?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is incorrect to assume that a general dicom image is supposed to have values ranging from 0-255 in MATLAB. If you look closely at the dicomread function help, it notes that the image class can be int8, uint8, int16 or uint16, meaning that negative values are indeed allowed.

See: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html

For example, try this in MATLAB:

```
class(dicomread('CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm')) % returns a int16, which can hold negative values
```

If you really want to convert all values into a uint8 type (which forces everything to be within 0-255), you could consider using im2uint8, like so:

```
out = im2uint8(inDCMmatrix);
```